# Ractive:execute one model's methods from another model

Tags: ractivejs

ref: [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL90wj45/5/)

(I don't know if this is a Ractive question or a plain-old-javascript question)

I have a Ractive model, "item":

```
window.item = new Ractive({
  el: "#container",
  template: "<p>words</p>",
  oninit: function() { window.little_ractive.set({ 'thing_to_do': this.do_this, 'item': this }); },
  do_this: function() { this.say("yeah baby"); },
  say: function(what) { console.log(what); }
});
```

Notice that the model initializes two attributes in *another* Ractive model, which looks like this:

```
window.little_ractive = new Ractive({
  finish: function() { this.get('thing_to_do').apply(this.get('item')); }
});
```

We can observe that little_ractive is properly initialized with attributes pointing to the item model and its "do_this" method.

If we now execute:

```
little_ractive.finish()
```

The context ('this') is incorrectly established in the "do_this" method, and it returns an error "this.say() is not a function"

How can the methods of one Ractive model be executed from another?

**update:** The jsfiddle uses Ractive version 1.0.0 build9. Ractive version 0.7.3 does not exhibit this problem, it works as one would expect.

**update:** The unexpected behaviour first appeared in version 0.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any functions that are stored at the root of a ractive instance's data are automatically bound to the instance e.g. `ractive.set('foo', function () { console.log('this will always be ractive'); })`. This is so that calling root functions execute as expected in templates.

If you move functions that *don't* need to be bound one level deep e.g. `ractive.set('fns.foo', function () { console.log('this is not bound'); })`, then you can pass them around and `call`/`apply` them as needed. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL90wj45/6/)